# Would a class in Linear Optimization/Programming be useful for a CS degree?

Tags: education

Would a class in Linear Optimization/Programming be useful for a CS degree?

What is it used for or how useful is it.

Can someone please help me decide.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what do you want to do after graduating. Linear Optimization/Programming is more theoretical  than practical, it will definetly be useful (take it) if you want to work as an academic/researcher but it won't be that helpful if you want to be a software developer.

Comment: So in short:
1. Academic/researcher: Take it.

2. Developer: Don't take it (unless there isn't something better).

Comment: This is plain wrong. Linear Programming can be *very* useful in practice (or "practice") because there are highly optimized solvers off the shelf. Expressing your problem at hand and applying such a solver can be an efficient way to solve it. (Of course, if your perspective is to write boring corporate data handling software or mostly-GUI apps, then you'll not need LPs. Or any computer *science*.)